# Which one is best in "self.view.window?.addSubview()" or "UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview()" in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to display loaderView in top of the viewcontroller

```
let loaderView: UIView()
self.view.window?.addSubview(loaderView)
```

Other type:

```
let loaderView: UIView()
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(loaderView)
```

Both line working fine, but Which code is best for adding subview... Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why not just `self.view.addSubview(loaderView)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are adding some view (not loader view) in your view controller on Appdelegate window then it's better to go with
`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(loaderView)`

otherwise

`self.view.window?.addSubview(loaderView)`

is fine.